# How to change Puppeteer Date Format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
var date = new Date();
var yesterday = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
yesterday = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
console.log(yesterday);
```

i want to use the date format dd/mm/yyyy
code I want the result I run in javascript : 21/03/2019
result I run in puppeteer : 3/21/2019
i don't wan't puppeteer result.

Why are the results different?
how to change puppeteer date format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace method to switch the places of `month` and `date`

```
/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/
```

```js
var date = new Date();
var yesterday = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
yesterday = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
console.log(yesterday)
console.log(yesterday.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$2/$1/$3'));
```

Comment: I run your code in puppeteer but result is
3/21/2019
3/21/2019

i want this format like 21/03/2019

Answer (score 0):

```
{
format: "A4",
printBackground: true,
displayHeaderFooter: true,
headerTemplate: `<div style="font-size:7px;white-space:nowrap;margin-left:38px;">
                    ${new Date().toDateString()}
                    <span style="margin-left: 10px;">Generated PDF</span>
                </div>`,
margin: {
  top: '38px',
  right: '38px',
  bottom: '38px',
  left: '38px'
} }
```

Change the date format in your required format.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer this question. Maybe you wanted to answer another question?